# Angular 4: Radiobutton-value disappears after another radiobutton is checked

Tags: javascript, html, angular, api, typescript

I have 3 radiobuttons, to sort different data from an API. On each radiobutton, the radiobutton-value disappears, if i press another radio-button, like so:
[image: This] and [image: this.].
I tried with property binding [value], but that caused an error.

TS:

```
  // Global inputvalues for Radiobuttons
  @Input() all: string; image: string; video: string; true: boolean; false: boolean;


  // Button-event payload
  @Output() mediaButtonSelectionChange: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();
  @Output() licenseButtonSelectionChange: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();
  @Output() verifiedButtinSelectionChange: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();

  sortMedia() {
    this.page = 0;
    this.hitsArray = [];
    this.mediaButtonSelectionChange.emit(this.mediaRadio);
    this.mediaType = this.mediaRadio;
    this.getStories(this.page, this.hits, this.feed, this.mediaType, this.query, this.verifiedType, this.licenseType, this.startDate, this.endDate);

  }
```

(The sortMedia() function has one for each radiobutton sorting because of the API calls).

HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid filter-btn">
  <button class="btn btn-sm gay-flame-btn-light filter-btn dropdown-toggle" type="button dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"
    aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Media type
    <span *ngIf="mediaType === 'all'" style="color:red;">(All)</span>
    <span *ngIf="mediaType === 'image'" style="color:red;">(Images)</span>
    <span *ngIf="mediaType === 'video'" style="color:red;">(Videos)</span>
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    <div class="radio-group">
      <div class="checkbox-forms gay-flame-forms form-group radio">
        <label class="form-check-label">
          <input type="radio" value='all' [(ngModel)]="mediaRadio" (change)="sortMedia()">
          <i aria-hidden="true" [class.active-check]="'all' === 'all'" class="fa fa-circle"></i> All</label>
        <label class="form-check-label">
          <input type="radio" value="image" [(ngModel)]="mediaRadio" (change)="sortMedia()">
          <i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-circle"></i> Images</label>
        <label class="form-check-label">
          <input type="radio" value="video" [(ngModel)]="mediaRadio" (change)="sortMedia()">
          <i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-circle"></i> Videos</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

(also this part has 3 separate parts for each radiobutton).

How do I keep the radiobutton-value on each radiobutton, if another button is pressed?

Comment: Are you sure you didn't bind them all to the same model or name ?

Comment: Yes. as you can see, the @Output() decorator is referring 3 different event emitters.

Comment: EventEmitter is only used to subscribe to events, the actual value of the radio button is stored in ngModel variable

Comment: Yes agree, but how do i keep the value in ngModel[()], when another radiobutton is active? I have 3 different ngModels for each radiobutton, so they shouldnt interfere with eachother?

Comment: You should have 1 model for each set of radio buttons, like `[(ngModel)]='mediaRadio'` for Media, `[(ngModel)]='licenseRadio'` for License etc etc ..., also you should give them name attribute although that's not required when working with Angular .... https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_radio

Comment: @AnteJablanAdamović: I already did that: mediaRadio: string = ''; licenseRadio: string = ''; verifiedRadio: string = '';.

Comment: Then i add the value from the radio through ngmodel for each button: this.mediaButtonSelectionChange.emit(this.mediaRadio);,     this.licenseButtonSelectionChange.emit(this.licenseRadio);,     this.verifiedButtinSelectionChange.emit(this.verifiedRadio);

Comment: @AnteJablanAdamović: See my answer, the name attribute was it. Even though its not required with angular. Thank you, friend!

Answer (score 2):

As provided by @AnteJablan, the solution was just (kinda weird) to add a name attribute to the HTML like so:

```
<input type="radio" name="verification" value="false" [(ngModel)]="verifiedRadio" (change)="sortVerification()">
```

Thank you Ante!